# @RunWith(Cucumber.class) error. The import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber; cannot be resolved

Tags: java, maven, selenium, cucumber

I am having this issue on all the cucumber runner files. Using the following dependencies in `pom.xml`. Any help will be appreciated.

I tried a clean and force update the project and restarted the IDE, 
deleted repository folder in `.M2` and then clean and force update the projects but it is still not working.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-core -->
<dependency>
<groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
<version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-html -->
<dependency>
<groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
<version>0.2.3</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
<dependency>
<groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
<version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
<dependency>
<groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
<version>1.0.5</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/gherkin -->
<dependency>
<groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
<artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
<version>2.12.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
<artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
<version>1.3</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-picocontainer -->
<dependency>
<groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
<version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng -->
<dependency>
<groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
<version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Extent Reports -->
<dependency>
<groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
<artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
<version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.freemarker/freemarker -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
<artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
<version>2.3.26-incubating</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
<dependency>
<groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
<version>3.6.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
<version>2.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Does the problem occur only in IDE or maven install from console reports the same error?

Comment: only in IDE. when i am trying to create the runner file for the cucumber .

Answer (score 0):

**1. You have added dependency of Cucumber-TestNG So you have to call Runner class with TestNG Runner syntax.**

Syntax for Cucumber with TestNG:

```
@CucumberOptions(features = "./src/main/java/cfeature", glue = {"stepd"}, monochrome = true,  plugin = { "pretty",  "html:Reports/cucumber-pretty" })

public class runnerDemo extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {   

}
```

*Its removing Junit annotation @RunWith and extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests class.*

**2. If you want to Run cucumber test with Junit, You need to replace Cucumber-testng depency with Cucumber-Junit. And your syntax will work fine.**

Answer (score 0):

cucumber-core
cucumber-java
cucumber-jUnit
use 1.2.6 version for all in pom.xml
all these dependencies must be in same version in order to solve this issue